# .NET Core Web API - await ResultExecutionDelegate doesn't await in IAsyncResultFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, filter, asp.net-core-webapi

```
    public class RenewTokenResultFilter : IAsyncResultFilter
    {
        public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("this run before response to client");
                      
           var resultContext = await next.Invoke();  // When the program finished executing this line, client get the response immediately...

           Debug.WriteLine("I expect this line should be ran before response to client");
        }
    }
```

Please consider the codes above.

I expect the `await next.Invoke()` should be ran before response has been sent to client. However, I don't know how come the response was sent to the client without waiting the result of `await next.Invoke()` and the 2nd `Debug.WriteLine()`.

Please advice, thanks!

Comment: `await next.Invoke()` executes the result, by design, which means your expectation isn't correct. Perhaps you can provide a bit more information on what you're trying to do. Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62653589/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-controllers-action-result-from-net-core-middleware), it seems you can interrogate `context.Result` to get the object that's about to be written to the response, modify it, and do so _before_ `await next.Invoke()`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin thank you for your assistance. I expect `IAsyncResultFilter` acts like `Middlewares`. Once execution reach `await next.Invoke()` then execution will be passed to next `Middlewares` and then the execution will come back in sequence. Doesn't `IAsyncResultFilter` acts like that as well?   What I am going to do is to update all of my `ActionResult`s with a renewed token by `IAsyncResultFilter`. Since I should do it after `Action` finished so that I want to `await next.Invoke()` beforehand.

Comment: It works the same way. When `OnResultExecutionAsync` is called, the action has already finished.

Comment: If you'd like to include the code you want to run against your `ActionResult`, I can post an example `IAsyncResultFilter` that demonstrates how it works.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin  Yes, I know that the action has already finished. What I mean is that seems the `await` here doesn't work... because the codes after `await next.Invoke()` executes after the http response has been sent out. The codes after `await next.Invoke()` were executed after client receive server response.